# reg ex for email to limit character

Tags: regex, xsd

How do I write a RegExp for an email so that it is a string less than 50 characters long and is ended with “.com” or “.org” or “.edu”, and the first character can not be a number?

Right now I have:

```
[a-z]{1}[a-zA-Z0-9]@.|edu|org|com|
```

and limiting the character length with a maxlength restriction rather than directly inside the RegEx.

Answer (score 0):

Your `.` after the `@` signifies that any single character can match, but only 1, and never more than one. The syntax for the "edu/org/com" grouping is also possibly incorrect.

Try the following:

```
[a-z]{1}[a-zA-Z0-9]*@.*\.(edu|org|com)$
```

Comment: `[edu|org|com]` should be `(edu|org|com)`

Comment: Cheers @Blender. Fixed. It did pass my quick (albeit, non-exhaustive) test in the Chrome Inspector. Glad you caught it.